# Create a dataframe from another dataframe in R

Tags: r

I need to create a dataframe with this info:

```
Boat Survived Not survived
Yes   amount1   amount2
No    amount3   amount4
```

The dataframe with the info is this:

```
Name  Survived  Boat
Peter    1       NA
Louis    1       NA
Candas   0       B
Karol    1       C
Lucy    1        3

0 = Not survived
1 = Survived
```

I am starting to learn R so I tried to count names after filtering by survived but I don't get the solution.

Can you help me?

I am starting to learn R so I tried to count names after filtering by survived but I don't get the solution.

Can you help me?

```
df$survived <- as.integer(df$survived)
  filter(df, survived==1)
```

from here how to count how many people survived?

I expect this df:

```
Boat Survived Not survived
Yes   amount1   amount2
No    amount3   amount4
```

Comment: Maybe `xtabs( ~ Boat + Survived, df)`. But I don't understand what you mean by `Boat` being `Yes/No`. How many people survived is just `sum(df$Survived)`.

Comment: Maybe you mean `table(df$Boat, df$Survived)`

Comment: I mean amount 1 is the total of people who survived and had a boat, amount 3 people who survived but did not have a boat.. etc.

Comment: How do you map `NA`, `B`, `C` and `3` to `Yes` and `No`? Is `NA` `No` and all else `Yes`?

Comment: Did you try my code? table is doing just that.

Comment: The problem is that I need to get values from the first df to the smaller df (3x3). In the original df I have the info if name had a boat or not and if they survived or not.

Comment: @schwantke thank you but I need to create another dataframe with the info and with your code I did not get it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to do a contingency table.

Here your data frame.

```
df

Name  Survived  Boat
Peter    1       NA
Louis    1       NA
Candas   0       B
Karol    1       C
Lucy     1       3
```

First replace the numbers with words, use `gsub`.

```
df$Survived<-gsub(1,"Yes",df$Survived)
df$Survived<-gsub(0,"No",df$Survived)
```

Then count the number of survivors, use `table`.

```
table(df$Survivor)

Yes No
 4  1
```

Also, you want to know how many had a boat, then use a flag indicating if they had one using `is.na` function.

```
df$flagboat<-c(1:nrow(df))
df$flagboat[which(is.na(df$Boat))]<-"No"
df$flagboat[which(!is.na(df$Boat))]<-"Yes"

table(df$flagboat,df$Survived)
```

Try it yourself!

Comment: Seems not to work as I suggested that already in the comments under the question

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo. Unfortunately flagboat does not work:  invalid function in complex assignment
In addition: Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: 'flag'.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote "Survivor" instead "Survived", try it again.

Comment: `table(df$Survived,df$flagboat)`